# Getting INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST while creating a record for CareRequestExtension

Tags: apex, picklist, dmlexception, health-cloud

All. I am trying to create a record for CareRequestExtension via apex. While creating the record I am providing non-existing values to some picklist fields of CareRequestExtension. For some picklist fields it is working and a record is getting created but for some picklist fields it throwing INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST.

For the following code, record is getting created even after providing a totally random value to DocumentAttachmentStatus:

```
CareRequestExtension cre = new CareRequestExtension();
cre.Name = 'Sample CRE From Apex 4';
cre.CareRequestCaseId = '500RO000002QBHvYAO';
cre.CareRequestId = '0UmRO00000001SV0AY';
cre.DocumentAttachmentStatus = 'Some Random Value';
insert cre;
```

And for the following code, I am getting INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST while providing a random value to CaseSubStatus:

```
CareRequestExtension cre = new CareRequestExtension();
cre.Name = 'Sample CRE From Apex 4';
cre.CareRequestCaseId = '500RO000002QBHvYAO';
cre.CareRequestId = '0UmRO00000001SV0AY';
cre.CaseSubStatus = 'Some Random Value';
insert cre;
```

Both DocumentAttachmentStatus and CaseSubStatus are picklist fields, and 'Some Random Value' is not present in both of them. But for the first one it is working and for second one it is failing.

Here is the full error message:

Line: 6, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Case Sub Status: bad value for restricted picklist field: Some Random Value: [CaseSubStatus]

What could be the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: Are you familiar with what restricted picklists are? Based on [the CareRequestExtension object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud_object_reference.meta/health_cloud_object_reference/sforce_api_objects_carerequestextension.htm), you should be getting an error on the first example (using `DocumentAttachmentStatus`) rather than the second example.

Comment: @DerekF There are 13 picklist fields in CareRequestExension and out of those 13 only 3 are throwing the error.